# Implementing a member function as an external function

Tags: c++, external

I am just beginning my advanced data structures class and one of our problems, when dealing with class basics, is to "implement the member function max() as an external function."

I have scoured the C++ primer, the C Programming Language, and our text, but all refer only to external variable declaration and talk about its usage as a global shortcut of sorts.

Would someone please help me figure out how to implement my member function externally and help me understand the logic behind the book asking this question?

My code:

democlass.h

```
#ifndef Assignment_1_democlass_h
#define Assignment_1_democlass_h

class demoClass
{
public:
    demoClass(int a = 5, int b = 10);
    int max() const;
    int getA() const; //my added code, not in provided text example
    int getB() const; //my added code, not in provided text example
private:
    int itemA, itemB;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "democlass.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    demoClass obj1(7,9);
    demoClass obj2(12);
    demoClass obj3;

    cout << obj1.getA() << " " << obj1.getB() << endl;
    cout << obj2.getA() << " " << obj2.getB() << endl;
    cout << obj3.getA() << " " << obj3.getB() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << obj2.max() << endl << obj3.max();

    return 0;
}
demoClass::demoClass(int a, int b){
    itemA = a;
    itemB = b;
}

int demoClass::max() const{
    if (itemA > itemB)
        return itemA;
    else
        return itemB;
};

int demoClass::getA() const{
    return itemA;
};

int demoClass::getB() const{
    return itemB;
};
```

Comment: Your functions definitions should be moved into a cpp file or marked inline, otherwise you will get linker errors if you include the header in more than one source file.

Comment: are you getting any errors

Comment: @aaronman @"Neil Kirk" I can change this; that was just a silly tangential mistake on my part, not related to my question.

Comment: Is there a *remote* chance they want you to implement a `const demoClass& max(const demoClass& lhs, const demoClass& rhs)` that returns the "max" object of the two (whatever that means) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig That's what I thought at first; pass the object by ref and get at the private data, but the original example didn't even provide getters, and we technically aren't allowed to "add" them, we have to work with the code provided, so unfortunately that route is impossible to take without a getter.

Comment: First, not true, You could `friend` the `max` free-function described prior. No getters required. but that aside, I've been at this for 20+ years, and honestly I'm taken back on their choice of vernacular. The only reasonable translation I can think of outside of what I provided above (a free-function that compares two objects) is they're intending to mean an out-of-line implementation (but I honestly don't see the point, and that this is in *advanced* data structures is disappointing in itself). This seems more a "WTF does that *mean*?" problem, and that your TA isn't helping much blows.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your commentary; I think the 'friend' route seems like the best option. I'm going to email my TA and see if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

does below code work?

```
inline int max(const demoClass& demo)
{
    return demo.max();
}
```

Comment: Actually, it does work in this current implementation, but is only accessing the member function. I need the function to work purely externally, as though I got rid of max() from the member list altogether.